# Scheduling Stored Procedure "ORACLE"

Tags: oracle

I want to create a stored procedure that contains an alter table and that is launched every night. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: and what exactly is your question? Where do you have a problem? What did you already investigate?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/schedover.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what is the problem in creating a job and schedule it via `DBMS_SCHEDULER`?

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
  3      job_name        => 'my_job_definition',
  4      job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  5      job_action      => 'BEGIN my_job_procedure; END;',
  6      start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
  7      repeat_interval => 'freq=daily',
  8      end_date        => NULL,
  9      enabled         => TRUE,
 10      comments        => 'Daily job to alter table');
 11  END;
 12  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT JOB_NAME, ENABLED FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS where job_name ='MY_JOB_DEFINITION'
  2  /

JOB_NAME                                 ENABL
---------------------------------------- -----
MY_JOB_DEFINITION                        TRUE
```